# Make unsigned ActiveX run in IE 9

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, security, activex

Here is the problem I have: I need a web page to execute an unsigned ActiveX control that is installed (with regsvr32) on my machine
I have the following snippet of the code:

```
<object id="terminal" classid="CLSID:C56DE417-5651-459E-828A-46C31CFD74CE" width="1" height="1">
</object>
```

and then a piece of JavaScript code:

```
res = terminal.SetConfiguration(0, 2, terminalIP, '2000');
```

I have enabled all possible security checks in Security Zones and when I open my web page from a server in my intranet - everything works fine. When I copy the page to the remote server and open it - it doesn't work. The error message is "Object does not support property or method" exactly on the line mentioned above.

As I said I have enabled everything possible in security zones, including adding the site into Trusted Websites zone. Still no luck.

It must be some obscure registry setting preventing IE from executing the control
Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to make it work unless you add the web page that creates the ActiveX to the "Local Intranet Zone"